# Old node that is still on monero v11 - Is this on a fork now? Is this considered Monero Original and Classic?

Tags: monero-forks, monero-original, monero-classic

I have an old node that is using monero cli v11. I'm guessing this is on a fork now.

- Can I load my old seed which is empty now to claim the monero original coins?
- What about monero classic? How do I claim that?
- So the asics being sold by bitmain is mining on the v11 client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes v11 is not supported anymore. And installing v11 of monero does put your on the old chain which is called classic / original. It will wither and die over time due to the lack of development on it. The only thing has it for them is the ASICs that are mining on it as there is no other use of the asics. Just stick with v12 software.